# FontSpec Error in Ubuntu and TexStudio

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec

I am using this code:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Courier New}
```

I am getting this error:

```
The font "CourierNew" cannot be found \setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Courier New}
```

I am using TexStudio 2.6.6 in Ubuntu 14.04. I am using XeLatex or LuaLatex in TexStudio and getting the same error.

I have also tried following fonts and got same kind of error.

```
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Hoefler Text}
```

or

```
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Times New Roman}
```

I have installed `texlive-fonts-extra`.

Can someone please help me to know what else I am missing or need to do?

**Edit:**
I have also tried deleting the whitespace between Courier New or others.

Comment: Since those are all proprietary fonts, I doubt Ubuntu has them by default and nor does a TeX distribution supply them. When you use Xe/LuaTeX, you are able to use system fonts, but only if your system provides them. Does `\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Ubuntu}` work?